# Connect raspberry pi to my computer via serial port

Tags: serial

I want to connect my raspberry pi directly to my computer using the serial port.I want to send data and receive data.

I have an old usb prolific cable that has 3 wires GND RX TX is is suitable to work with the pi ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [article on this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection) - it is possible but takes little play to accomplish. If your cable contains USB<->Serial chip ([like one here](https://www.modmypi.com/gpio-accessories/USB-to-TTL-Serial-Cable-Debug-Console-Cable-for-Raspberry-Pi)), it should work. But with USB/ethernet available - why? :)

Comment: I am trying to emulate a device which outputs some data on the serial so the application running on Windows Machine can interpret it.I know I can use a virtual serial driver to emulate the serial port on the windows machine but I tought it will be nice

Comment: I'd use an emulator when possible - less chances you burn something :)

Answer (score 0):

yes,it is possible with the available rx,tx,ground pins of serial port to connect with the raspi b,b+.we can connect the raspi board to the lap by inserting this serial port pins into the GPIOs of raspi board.